# Flex-layout with Angular 6 vertical 50-50 height

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular6, angular-flex-layout

I'm using FlexLayoutModule with Angular6 and trying to achieve two div's of both 50% height vertically. I have tried this particular code but both are not occupying 50% height of parent.

```
<div style="min-height:50px">I'm header</div>
<div style="height:100%">
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="12px">
    <div fxFlex="50%" style="background:#5896FF">
        <h1>I should occupy 50% height of my parent</h1>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50%" style="background:#525252">
        <h1>I should occupy 50% height of my parent</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link of so far working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-95bw52?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[This is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t0Ee.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to your example to have two div's split the screen vertically 50 / 50.

```
<div style="height:100%" fxLayout="column">
    <div style="min-height:50px">I'm header</div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="12px" fxFlex>
        <div fxFlex style="background:#5896FF">
            <h1>I should occupy 50% height of my parent</h1>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex style="background:#525252">
            <h1>I should occupy 50% height of my parent</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You also need to update styles.css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Here is a link to the updated example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-txbmtb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 50vh instead of 50% . it will use 50% of the vertical height.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="12px" style="">
<div fxFlex="50vh" style="background:#5896FF">
    <h1>I should occupy 50% height</h1>
</div>
<div fxFlex="50vh" style="background:#525252">
    <h1>I should occupy 50% height</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that but my container is 100% of body, it has got two header of 50 px.

Comment: If I use 50vh it scrolls down the height of my header. but I want to fit my parent height.